# How to forward email automatically in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, email-forwarding

This should be simple but it is not. I do not want all my email forwarded to some email address, I want to create rules and based on the rule, I want to forward the email to appropriate email address, how? It keeps forcing me to enter an email in Forwarding and POP/IMAP but I do not want to forward all email or need to verify the email where I am forwarding to. This should be trivial.

Comment: You have to setup the forwarding address the same way regardless if it is in use or not.  Just because you have a forwarding address setup doesn't mean it is in use.  Set it up.  Don't enable it.  Use it in your filter.

Comment: Please add a brief description of  your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].